# Op-Amps in custom current limiter acting strangely

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, analog, current-limiting

I'm building a small current limiter (~20 mA). It's important that there is little drop over the current limiter and that the load receives almost the full supply voltage when it's pulling less than max current, so I chose not to use a pure BJT solution that would require at least .5 volts of drop (to make the BE junction conduct). So, I've developed this schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiwvZ5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I thought this circuit would limit current to about 5mA. When the current reaches 5mA, the drop over the sense resistor R3 should be about 10mV. OA2 should amplify this to 1V. This will go to the comparator OA3, which will go low and deactivate Q1, decreasing the current to the load. However, it's not working, either in the circuitlab simulation or in real life. In the simulation, circuitlab says the non-inverting input on OA2 is about 200mV while the inverting input is almost grounded, yet the output is still grounded. So, it doesn't activate OA3 and current is unlimited (nearly 100mA). In real life, it seems to fail for a different reason. OA2's inputs are equal and it amplifies as expected, but OA3 isn't comparating as it should be; the output still stays at a 1-1.5 volt that's enough to drive Q1 after the inverting input has gone higher than the non-inverting one. That being said, the real life version still decreases the current to some extent -- but it doesn't have a hard cutoff point like I want it to.

When I replace the op-amps in the simulator with ideal op-amps, the circuit works as expected, limiting current to just under 5mA as soon as the load gets too small. What is it about a real LM324 op-amp that is causing this circuit to fail? The LM324 datasheet indicates that it can handle common-mode inputs all the way down to ground.

EDIT: I think something was wrong with the 734 unit I was using. After replacing it, the current is successfully limited to the maximum design value. However, OA3 still isn't behaving as I would expect -- when the current drops below 5mA, I would expect it to drive the output as high as it can, fully saturating Q1. However, even when the inverting input is 20mV lower than the non-inverting input, the output stays at 1.5V or so, partially limiting the current and keeping Q1 in the active region.

Comment: When you use the generic op-amp (with no power supplies shown) they are actually powered by +/-15V. This allows them to drive your Q1 base above 5V. Your practical circuit is limited to about 2.8V output. Replace Q1 with a P-channel FET and swap OA3 inputs as a starting point.

Comment: Is this a single-rail system? In other words, your load and your opamps must all use exactly the same rail and ground?

Comment: @jonk Yeah, it is a USB-powered system. I believe the LM324 can handle common-mode inputs at Vcc-, however.

Comment: @markasoftware Is this to be a voltage-controlled current source? (Are you aware that there really isn't too much of a problem with allowing a BJT to go into soft saturation as part of a current mirror? You can achieve very low overhead with a very easy to understand concept, that way. And your voltages will all be inside your rails.)